# The way to understand the first paragraph in the Introduction of David Hume's A Treatise of Human Nature

Tags: complex-sentences, philosophy

I don't really understand some sentences in the Introduction of David Hume's A Treatise of Human Nature, here they are:

> Nothing is more usual and more natural for those, who pretend to discover anything new to the world in philosophy and the sciences, than to insinuate the praises of their own systems, by decrying all those, which have been advanced before them. ***And indeed were they content with lamenting that ignorance, which we still lie under in the most important questions, that can come before the tribunal of human reason, there are few, who have an acquaintance with the sciences, that would not readily agree with them.***

So my question is: I don't really understand what the grammar it used in those words which are Bold and Italic. What did Hume mean with "that ignorance"?

I do appreciate anyone who'd like to give me a hand! Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't agree that this is the original.

Comment: It's a long, run-on, metaphorical, multiple negation sentence characteristic of that time. 'That ignorance' is described in the following clauses. There are _way_ too many commas. Also a typo: some->come.

Comment: TL;DR "People who discover new things tend to say old things aren't as clever. Even if there are still unknowns, there are many that would agree". There's a lot more nuance of course.

Comment: I'd say that it's badly written and confusing.  It feels like it should start a new sentence after "tribunal of human reason".

Comment: My gratitude to all of you :))

Answer (score 1):

The full paragraph makes it clearer, I think

```
    Nothing is more usual and more natural for those, who pretend to 
discover anything new to the world in philosophy and the sciences,
than to insinuate the praises of their own systems, by decrying all
those, which have been advanced before them. And indeed were they
content with lamenting that ignorance, which we still lie under in the
most important questions, that can come before the tribunal of human
reason, there are few, who have an acquaintance with the sciences, that
would not readily agree with them. It is easy for one of judgment and 
learning, to perceive the weak foundation even of those systems, which
have obtained the greatest credit, and have carried their pretensions
highest to accurate and profound reasoning. Principles taken upon trust,
consequences lamely deduced from them, want of coherence in the parts,
and of evidence in the whole, these are every where to be met with in
the systems of the most eminent philosophers, and seem to have drawn
disgrace upon philosophy itself.
```

So he is saying that "those, who pretend to discover anything new" tend to "insinutate the praises" of their own work by "decrying all" who came before.  Hume then makes the point that the majority of those "who have an acquaintance with the sciences" would agree that most existing theories have "ignorance" underlying the answers to the "most important questions"

He then goes on to say that "It is easy" to see these weaknesses in even the most respected systems of knowledge

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much for that explanation!
And indeed, I do understand it now! Those who pretend to discover anything new are actually benefiting themselves rather than the entire human race. And with that benefit of those weaknesses in even the most respected systems of knowledge, they make it easier to fool people with their pretentious and in fact ignorant fake theory. But those people who have ever accessed to science or similar understanding frame can spot this truth that those people were faking easily.
Thank you all for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the phrase "that ignorance" is indirectly drawn from the preceding sentence.  It is the ignorance created by people denying sincere attempts at understanding the world to make themselves look better.

Hume started by talking about those that "decry all" who came before them, in order to make their own work look more impressive (that is, "insinuate" or suggest the praise of their own systems) at the expense of others' work previously.  I think it is relevant, though, that he specifically labels these people as "those who pretend to discover anything new" - *not* people actually making advances but who are egotistical or insecure, and tear down others' work to play up their own, but people who *are not discovering anything new* who pretend discoveries to cover up this lack.

So, in this case - the ignorance would be the result of the two actions.  With people tearing down old theories, pointing out weaknesses and flaws in those arguments *and yet* not giving better theories or real discoveries to fill those gaps, there is a growing ignorance.  With people pretending ideas and theories that aren't new and aren't genuinely and rigorously discovered, and instead are built up by decrying others' work rather than their own merit - people who rely on these flawed ideas are creating this ignorance.  When old knowledge and ideas are lost because people are tearing it down, and what looks like new knowledge is just people's posturing.  That is how he is getting to the "disgrace on philosophy itself" that ends the paragraph.

It is easy to show "that ignorance", that underlying ignorance of the "most important questions", he claims, when everyone is questioning the old theories but no one is giving credible replacements.  It is easy to find people pulling the ideas apart and find them wanting - but people are supposed to do so in order to to discover new things, to better theories and make new discoveries.  If people are giving false theories instead, the whole system starts to look bad - as old theories look less and less credible, and there are no *good* new ones to take their place, nothing people can take on faith and work with.

And all the contradictory theories, all the *pretensions*, mask any true ideas and prevent people from building on and strengthening sincere, but possibly flawed ones.  And without people being able to find the good ideas out of the bad ones, or build on them to be better, there is "that underlying ignorance".

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation that's full of patience and knowledge!
And I understand it now that why David Hume said those who're just being pretentious would be content with that ignorance. They are happy with that ignorance under which we're still lie in every branch of human understanding for they only care about their own interests and benefits, rather than those of all human beings.

Comment: @RandolphWeng - I'm glad you found it helpful!